# MariaDB - delete all values that are `not the max` of one column with a group by on another column

Tags: mariadb

I have a table that is a list of updates over time `timeOfOfferChange`.   I can grab the most recent value with the query below but is there a way to delete all the records that are not the max?

```
select asin, uniqueid,  max(timeOfOfferChange) from tbl_sqs group by asin
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use exists logic:

```sql
DELETE
FROM tbl_sqs t1
WHERE uniqueid NOT IN (SELECT uniqueid
                       FROM (
                           SELECT t2.uniqueid
                           FROM tbl_sqs t2
                           WHERE t2.asin = t1.asin AND
                                 t2.timeOfOfferChange > t1.timeOfOfferChange
                       ) t);
```

Comment: This throws a non-descrpt 'check syntax near t1'.    Two questions 1)What does the 1 in `SELECT 1 FROM tbl_sqs t2` do?  2)I need to grab the values that are not the latest for each `asin` that was in the group by.   But maybe I can turn query#1 in to a view and then delete all the records that dont have the same unique id

Comment: I have updated my answer per your revealed desired logic.

Comment: That throws a similar syntax error then original but sytax seems reasonable  to m me  What does SELECT 1 do?   Query generally makes sense.. `Delete from t1 version of tbl_sqs any row where there is another record found in t2 of tbl_sqs with a later time of offer for that asin.`  I dont know what the syntax error i

Comment: Not sure what syntax tool you are using here, but exists logic is a very common thing.

Comment: I am just dropping query in to table plus. To be fair I am using Maria DB which is a MySQL fork but never had a syntax issue before that was unique to Maria DB.   Agree I have used `where exists many times`..

Comment: Even when I make it more simple and create a view I get similar MySQL error. delete 
FROM tbl_sqs t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM view_tbl_sqs_latest_by_asin t2
              WHERE t2.asin = t1.asin AND
                    t2.maxTimeOfOfferChange > t1.timeOfOfferChange)

Comment: I guess you can't use `tbl_sqs` again in `WHERE` clause when `DELETE`